# Java how to create a .png file?

Tags: java, image, swing, io, jpanel

Is there a way to save a JPanel's paintComponent contents into a .png file? Preferably with java.io or some other built-in library. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the [ImageIO class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)'s methods, in particular the `write(...)` method.

Answer (score 7):

1. create a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`
2. get a `java.awt.Graphics` by `BufferedImage.createGraphics()`
3. Pass the `Graphics` to `JPanel.paintComponent()`
4. Use `javax.imageio.ImageIO.write()` to save it

Comment: +1 [Writing/saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) for more details